# Sum of SQL instead of a list result

Tags: sql, sql-server

Instead of have a list of rows with daily budget, I just wan't the total SUM of DalyBudget.

How do I do that?

```
SELECT 


       (b.MonthBudget /
        SUM(wd.WorkingDay) OVER (PARTITION BY YEAR(wd.date), MONTH(wd.date))
       )
       
       as DalyBudget


FROM [Navision4].[dbo].[Salesboard Working Days] wd OUTER APPLY
     (SELECT COALESCE(ABS(SUM(Amount)), 0) as MonthBudget
      FROM [Navision4].[dbo].[Selek Danmark$G_L Budget Entry] b
      WHERE MONTH(wd.Date) = MONTH(b.Date) AND
            YEAR(wd.date) = YEAR(b.Date) AND
            b.[Budget Name] = '2020C' AND
            b.[G_L Account No_] LIKE '3%'
     ) b
WHERE wd.WorkingDay = 1 AND
      wd.SalesPersonCode IS NULL AND
      wd.companycode = 'Selek Danmark' AND
      wd.[Date] >= '2020-07-27' AND wd.[Date] <= '2020-08-17'
```

Current result:

[image: Current result]

I'm not so good til advanced SQL, and this dosen't work

```
SUM(    
      (b.MonthBudget /
       SUM(wd.WorkingDay) OVER (PARTITION BY YEAR(wd.date), MONTH(wd.date))
      )
   )
   as DalyBudget
```

Comment: `Sum` against what ? per `WorkingDay` or per `companycode` ?

Comment: what about ```SELECT SUM(DalyBudget) FROM ( *insert your sql here* ) tbl1```

Comment: @Sujitmohanty30 Total sum with both

Answer (score 1):

This is because of your `OUTER APPLY` results, simply add `DISTINCT` keyword before you select it.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
       (b.MonthBudget / SUM(wd.WorkingDay) OVER (PARTITION BY YEAR(wd.date), MONTH(wd.date))) AS DalyBudget        
FROM [Navision4].[dbo].[Salesboard Working Days] wd OUTER APPLY
     (
        SELECT COALESCE(ABS(SUM(Amount)), 0) as MonthBudget
        FROM [Navision4].[dbo].[Selek Danmark$G_L Budget Entry] b
        WHERE MONTH(wd.Date) = MONTH(b.Date) AND YEAR(wd.date) = YEAR(b.Date) AND
                b.[Budget Name] = '2020C' AND b.[G_L Account No_] LIKE '3%'
     )b
WHERE wd.WorkingDay = 1 AND wd.SalesPersonCode IS NULL AND wd.companycode = 'Selek Danmark' AND 
      wd.[Date] >= '2020-07-27' AND wd.[Date] <= '2020-08-17'
```

Comment: Sorry, that not do the job

Comment: @Kevin It should. Can you create the [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/) for it?